# Javascript prototype inheritance vs jQuery extend

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette, prototypal-inheritance

I am using the following code to inherit from Marionette's Item View class:

```
Base.ItemView = function (options) {

    var baseItemViewConstructor = function () {

        this._itemViewVent = new Marionette.EventAggregator();

        this._itemViewController = null;

        this._data = null;

        Marionette.ItemView.apply(this, [options]);                
    };   

// inherit from Marionette's Item view
    baseItemViewConstructor.prototype = new Marionette.ItemView();

    baseItemViewConstructor.prototype = {
        constructor: baseItemViewConstructor,                

        getData: function () {
            return this._data;
        }
// , many other functions go here.
 };    

    return baseItemViewConstructor;
}();

Base.ItemView.extend = Marionette.ItemView.extend;
```

And the code using jQuery extend or underscore extend is :

```
jQuery.extend(EY.ATF.Tool.Common.Base.ItemView.prototype, Marionette.ItemView.prototype, {

    getData: function () {
        return this._data;
    }
});

Base.ItemView.extend = Marionette.ItemView.extend;
```

And when I use my own Base.ItemView class inherited from Marionette's Item view in my derived class,

```
 View.CreateMyOwnView = Base.ItemView.extend({
```

I get an error using prototype inheritance saying render is not a function. When I examined the instance of my base class using prototype inheritance, the render, serializeData and many other prototype methods were not copied from Marionette class. But JQuery extend does this beautifully.

So, how to imitate jQuery extend behaviour in prototype chaining?

Thanks,
Mandar Katre.

Comment: Couldn't you just call ItemView.extend to create your BaseItemView?

Comment: Yeah, ItemView.extend works only if I create my BaseItemView using jQuery extend from the Marionette's Item view class. But its not working with prototype inheritance.

Comment: no... I'm saying do var BaseItemView = ItemView.extend({ whatever });  var MyOwnView = BaseItemView.extend({ whateverElese });

Comment: I think Robert is correct. To sub class the ItemView, you just do Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({});.  I'm working on a large Marionette application and I have several sub classes (I like to relate JavaScript to OOP sometimes) that I have created so I am not rewriting the same code over and over again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone: annoying behaviour of prototype object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950479/backbone-annoying-behaviour-of-prototype-object)